# How to make transform scale do not overflow?

Tags: css, overflow, transform

I'm beginner to CSS & HTMl, and for now I am practicing on templates, i wanted to make a zoom effect using transform scale and overflow hidden (without overflowing the image borders, as in [Snapshot Template](https://templated.co/snapshot)), i made transform scale [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HASHEM5/6my7k45g/1/), but i didn't manage to make a trick and make zoom effect, can anyone help me?

```
.gallery-grid img {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: overflow:hidden should go to the parent element

Comment: tried so, didnt worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap every image into a container div and give overflow: hidden to it

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/G9CYqz6/01.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pbjtTMD/05.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ckv3dPy/09.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/p0kYsQR/02.jpg">
</div>
...
```

and

```
.image-container {
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: why it is overflowing from the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply `overflow: hidden` on an `img`.

You should apply it to the container which you do not want it to bleed out of.

Comment: i tried that, but the images overflowing on each other within the container.

Comment: which part of your jsfiddle are you referencing?

Comment: from line 133 to 182.

Comment: You need to wrap all over your images in a `div` and add `overflow: hidden` on to the wrapping `div`.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `z-index`and `position` , so scaled element remains under others. Also lay theme all the way throught and all the way down, overflow on the container will be hidding what overflows from the top and the bottom of itself.

To avoid to deal with this this way, wrap each image in a container , so overflow works for each of them.

Demo  from your HTML and CSS updated 
https://jsfiddle.net/c5ae48vL/

modification made on lines about z-index and container grid-column and height:

```
// modifications made
//line 140
//line 141
//line 149
//line 158
//line 176
```

or snippet below

```js
// modifications made
//line 140
//line 141
//line 149
//line 158
//line 176

// and transition turned to transform instead all
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://templated.co/snapshot -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Snapshot</title>
        <style>
            @import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css";

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto Light";
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Side Nav Bar */

aside {
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(13, 18, 23);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
}

aside i {
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgb(134, 137, 139);
}

aside i:hover {
    color: white;
}

aside i:active {
    color: rgb(134, 137, 139);
}

.fas.fa-home {
    color: #19b5fe;
}

/* End Of Side Nav Bar */

/* Main Section */

main {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#banner-img {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 2;

}

.banner {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/KKpJvX3/banner.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-fore {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.main-fore h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.main-fore h2 {
    border: 2px solid rgb(82, 72, 63);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 15%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.main-fore h2:hover {
    background: rgba(72, 57, 44, .2);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

/* End Of Main Section */

/* Gallery Section - What's New */

.gallery {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 500px;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 800px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

#g-head {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    color: rgb(34, 49, 63);
    font-size: 25px;
}

.gallery-grid img {
    -webkit-transition:  transform .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:  transform .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;

}

.gallery-grid img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    z-index:0;
}

.gallery-grid {
    width: 100%;
  /*  height: 100%;*/ max-width: 1000px;margin:0 auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 27% 27%;
    grid-template-areas: ". . . ." ". . . .";

}

#g-button {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
    background: #19b5fe;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index:20;
}

#g-button:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(1, 155, 227);
}

/* End Of What's New Section */

/* About Me Section */

.aboutme {
    width: 47.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1300px;
    z-index: 3;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    right: 47%;
    color: rgb(34,49,63);
    height: 70%;
}

.aboutme h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.aboutme p {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-right: 7%;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.socialicons i {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    user-select: none;
    color: #19b5fe;
    margin: 3px;
}

.socialicons i:hover {
    color: rgb(1, 155, 227);
}

/* End Of About Me Section */

/* Message Section */

.message {
    width: 47.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1300px;
    background: #ececec;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 70%;
}

.message h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(34,49,63);
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.name_email {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.name_field {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.email_field {
    flex: 1;
}

.message_field {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.email_field input, .name_field input, .message_field textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid #bde6fc;
}

#submit_button {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background: #19b5fe;
    color: white;
    padding: 2% 7%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#submit_button:hover {
    background: rgb(1, 155, 227);
}

/* End Of Message Section */

/* Footer Section */

#footer-cap  {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    color: black;
}

.no1-img {
    overflow: hidden;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside>
            <a href="Snapshot.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a><br>
            <a href="gallery.html"><i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i></a><br>
            <a href="generic.html"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></a>
        </aside>
        <main>
            <div class="banner">
                <div id="banner-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-fore">
                <h1>Hey, I'm Snapshot</h1>
                <h2>Continue</h2>    
            </div>
        </main>
        <div class="gallery">
            <h1 id="g-head">What's New</h1>
            <div class="gallery-grid">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/G9CYqz6/01.jpg">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pbjtTMD/05.jpg">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ckv3dPy/09.jpg">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/p0kYsQR/02.jpg">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7pgbSk9/06.jpg">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0F93gYK/10.jpg">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0Yw8zwd/03.jpg">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wwnzstm/07.jpg">
            </div>
            <a id="g-button" href="gallery.html">Full Gallery</a>
        </div>
        <div class="middlediv">
            <div class="aboutme">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
                <p>Mus sed interdum nunc dictum rutrum scelerisque erat a parturient condimentum potenti dapibus vestibulum condimentum per tristique porta. Torquent a ut consectetur a vel ullamcorper a commodo a mattis ipsum class quam sed eros vestibulum quisque a eu nulla scelerisque a elementum vestibulum.<br><br><br>Aliquet dolor ultricies sem rhoncus dolor ullamcorper pharetra dis condimentum ullamcorper rutrum vehicula id nisi vel aptent orci litora hendrerit penatibus erat ad sit. In a semper velit eleifend a viverra adipiscing a phasellus urna praesent parturient integer ultrices montes parturient suscipit posuere quis aenean. Parturient euismod ultricies commodo arcu elementum suspendisse id dictumst at ut vestibulum conubia quisque a himenaeos dictum proin dis purus integer mollis parturient eros scelerisque dis libero parturient magnis.</p>
                <h1>Follow Me</h1>
                <div class="socialicons">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message Section -->
            <div class="message">
                <h1>Get in Touch</h1>
                <form action="#" method="POST" id="message_form">
                    <div class="name_email">
                        <div class="name_field">
                            <label for="name">Name</label><br><br>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="user_name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="email_field">
                            <label for="email">Email</label><br><br>
                            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="user_email" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="message_field">
                        <label for="message_area">Message</label><br><br>
                        <textarea cols="20" rows="7" id="message_area" placeholder="Message" name="user_message" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send" form="message_form">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Of Message Section -->
        <footer>
            <div style="width:95%; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: 3; background: rgb(242, 242, 242); top: 1900px; right: 0; left: 5%;" class="footer">
                <p id="footer-cap">© Snapshot: HASHEM. Images: Unsplash.</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is overflowing from the bottom, how can i fix this?

Comment: @HaSHeM5 i had removed height:100%; on the gallery container , did you too ?

Comment: I did the gallery container was disappeared.

Comment: @HaSHeM5 okay, i guess your code was not exactly what you provided in the question ;) snippet and codepen work fine.